# How to uninstall Windows without removing data in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I'm a beginner in Oracle and I want to know how I can uninstall Windows without losing the data saved before in my database system.

Another related question is:

To avoid this later can I install Oracle 11g in another partition different from the one contains Windows?

Comment: How safe do yo need it to be? Are you trying to protect from user error (eg, accidentally dropping a table), or are you trying to protect the data in case of an earthquake in your data center?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I want to know how I can uninstall windows without losing the data saved before in my database system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datapump export to create an export file of your data. This can then be re-imported into another database.

Comment: Thanks alot it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you have 2 partitions.  Do a full export of your database (using exp or datapump) onto the other partition (let's say you called it drive D:).  Then when you reinstall windows, you can import using imp or datapump.

You can also shutdown your database then copy all your datafiles over to drive D:.  Be careful not to miss out the online redo files, and all datafiles, as well as your admin folder.

Then you can safely format the first partition (drive C:) and reinstall windows on drive C:.  You can then install oracle on drive D: and create your database files there too.  Note however if you reinstall windows, the RDBMS software will not work any more but your database will be intact on drive D:

Comment: Thanks alot it really helped me